# Should I apply the subsurf modifier before rigging so I have enough loops for deformation?

Tags: modeling, rigging, workflow, subdivision-surface

I've been modeling quite a lot this past month, and started making my humanoid models in 'T' pose so I can rig them and pose them. But I've been wondering what the workflow is when you are modeling something that's going to have a rig. I start modeling something simple using the subdivision modifier to make it look smooth, but I've always applied the subdivision modifier to start doing the rig, in fear that I wont have enough loops to make smooth poses for my character, but I would like to leave that modifier just in case I want to do something else later.

How you guys do it?

Comment: you don't need to apply the modifier, it will make the mesh harder to animate, and harder to edit in case you want to change the topology. Also, put the Armature modifier above the Subsurf

Comment: Yeah, I just tested it with something simple. I wish I hadn't applied the sub mod on my complex models so I could test this more.

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.